# Dart interface can be extended?

Tags: dart

The official documentation says that an interface cannot be inherited. When I try to test this, I come across the fact that both androidstudio and dart pad allow me to do this. Why?

I expect behavior as in the documentation, what am I doing wrong?
docs https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#interface
[image: you can try this]

Comment: The example is showing that `Car` that is in b.dart can't extend the `Vehicle` interface that is defined in a.dart

Comment: The class modifiers only prevent *other libraries* from implementing, extending, or both, the modified class. Inside the same library, like here, you can mostly ignore the modifiers (except that if the superclass is `final` or `base`, the subclass must also be `final`, `base` or `sealed`, which isn't technically necessary, but is there to protect you from accidentally opening the class to other libraries in a subclass).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Libraries outside of the interface's own defining library can implement the interface, but not extend it"

According to dart [documentation](https://dart.dev/language/libraries#:%7E:text=Every%20Dart%20file%20(plus%20its%20parts)%20is%20a%20library%2C%20even%20if%20it%20doesn%27t%20use%20a%20library%20directive.) - "Every Dart file (plus its parts) is a library, even if it doesn't use a library directive."

So, you can't extend it in another file/library.